# I want to move left this post, i mean i want to add negative left margin, how can i?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to move left this post, i mean i want to add negative left margin, how can i?
i am unable to move this post left side please help me to move this post left side, its a youtube embeded code.
I have to paste it on my blog.
Help me experts.
Thank u

```html
<iframe width="238" height="136" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h5yKGDlFiV0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: You've determined you want to add a margin. You've managed to tag the question with [tag:css]. What's the problem? Have you read an introductory CSS tutorial?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set `position:relative` on the parent container and then you will be able to give negative left margin to the iframe. Not sure what your surrounding markup is, but here's an example:

```
<div class="video-wrap">
     <iframe width="238" height="136" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h5yKGDlFiV0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.video-wrap {position:relative;}
.video-wrap iframe {margin-left:-15px;}
```

Comment: I did include code in my answer. Do you know how to edit a CSS file?

Comment: can u tell me just one more thing? if you don't mind

Comment: Sure, but if it's unrelated to this question, it would be best to create a new one. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.